# Local Host Refused

Tags: android, httpconnection

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "product_name", product_name));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brand",
                                brand_product));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reference_price",
                                mrp_product));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("model",
                                model_product));

                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/wic3/wic2/product/doadd");

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                nameValuePairs));
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        String response = SignUpActivity.httpclient.execute(
                                httppost, responseHandler);
                        Log.d("response", response);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ShareProductActivity.this, ShareActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

this gives me an exception:

`05-07 14:56:19.105: D/exception(1137): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused`

i searched for this and everyone says change `127.0.0.1` to `10.0.2.2`, but i am not using `127.0.0.1`
I guess the problem is at this step:

```
String response = SignUpActivity.httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Comment: where is your http client declare ?

Comment: did u take permission from android mainfest.xml for accessing the internet?

Comment: my http client is in some other class...it is public static....i am using the same client in every activity....every activity is working fine except this. and yes i added internet permission in my manifest.xml

Comment: have you called local url in every activity ? means localhost url (10.0.2.2)

Comment: yeah the code is almost same....the only difference is the data i am sending and to what controller.

Comment: doadd is it php file or java file ? please specify the extension in url

Comment: doadd is a function in php file product.php....but till now i never specified php extension in my url n every thing was 5n

Comment: is the link is proper ? Please check the link once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localhost by definition refers to the hosting system - the android device itself.  Unless you are trying to contact a server running on the android device, it will not work for you.

Follow the advice of those who suggested that you change the 127.0.0.1 (which is what localhost is a name for) to the forwarding alias for the machine hosting the emulator.

Note however, that **this only works with the emulator** and not with real devices.

Comment: thankyou....but i am using 10.0.2.2 and thats what wrote in my question. Local host is not the problem

Comment: @Archie.bpgc If you claim not to be using localhost, then why did you post this error message: "Connection to http:// localhost refused"  ???

Comment: because that is the error im getting....i searched about it for 2-3 hrs n the only thing i found is change localhost or 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2, which is fine in my case

Comment: Clearly something is using it.  Can you do a search on your entire code base for localhost?  Or post the whole logcat surrounding that error so we can see where it is coming from?  could be that is not even an error in your app, though presumably there is an error in your app or you would not have posted a question.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do.

Use 1`http://10.0.2.2:8080/` instead your IP Address

Close your `eclipse` and `avd` and ReStart them.

Comment: thankyou....but i am using 10.0.2.2 and thats what wrote in my question. Local host is not the problem